# I am getting the following errors in Android Studio "Android Resource Linking Failed"

Tags: android-studio

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\NASIR CHANGEZI\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstProject\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:25: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka com.example.nasirchangezi.myfirstproject:style/AppTheme) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.

Command: C:\Users\NASIR CHANGEZI\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\7c69ee26222ec96ad56e657c99f59917\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\NASIR CHANGEZI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\NASIR CHANGEZI\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstProject\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\NASIR CHANGEZI\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstProject\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\NASIR CHANGEZI\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstProject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\NASIR CHANGEZI\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstProject\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.nasirchangezi.myfirstproject\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\NASIR CHANGEZI\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstProject\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your android manifest you are referencing a style "AppTheme". Check your res/values/.xml files if they contain this resource, if not, add it.